# Why isn't this Javascript email validation only validating first if statement?

Tags: javascript

So, I'm working on a page with a contact form, and I want to have it check if field's are empty.  I'm using this simple code below, but it only works for the first if.  It only displays "I want to know who you are" when I click submit.  It just doesn't even see the other if statements!

```
function validation() {

var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;

if(name == null || name == "") {
document.getElementById("name-error").innerHTML = "I want to know who you are!";
return false;
}

if(email == null || email == "") {
document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = "Give me your email!";
return false;
} 

if(subject == null || subject == "") {
document.getElementById("subject-error").innerHTML = "I need a subject!";
return false;
}

if(message == null || message == "") {
document.getElementById("message-error").innerHTML = "Don't forget your message!";
return false;
}

}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
                <form name="contact" id="contact" action="./assets/send.php" method="post" id="form">

                <label>Full name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><span id="name-error"></span>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><span id="email-error"></span>
                <label>Subject</label>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"><span id="subject-error"></span>
                <label>Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea><span id="message-error"></span>
                <button onclick="return validation()" type="submit" name="send" id="send">Send</button>

            </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling firebug in firefox and checking if it generates JS errors? Usually that's the case

Comment: If you see the first error then you automatically have a `return false;` which ends your function...

Comment: So, I should only have on return false; at the last if?

Comment: No, you should use a flag variable and return the flag status. No doubt someone will post an example soon.

Comment: Why do you compare a value to `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `return false;` inside the `if()` , so the control returns after executing that `if()` block.

```
if(name == null || name == "") {
  document.getElementById("name-error").innerHTML = "I want to know who you are!";
  return false; // control returns from the function here.
}
```

It would be better if you can keep a local variable inside the function and return it at the end of the function. Set it to `true` initially , change it to `false` inside `if(){}` blocks and return it as the last statement of the function.

```
function validation() {
   var isValid = true;
   if(someThingWrong) {
     // execute your logic here
     isValid = false;
   }
   return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works!  The only thing wrong now, is if, let's say, I only enter my email in the first time, then enter my name in the second time, it still sends the message even with the other two fields empty.  But, I think this might be because this code is too simple or something.

Answer (score 0):

Because you `return false;` inside all if conditions, when one of them is met, it halts execution thereon. If you must use the return statement, put it right at the end, after all the if statements.